# Deploying rails app to wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to post my blogs from rails app to Wordpress, using this gem https://github.com/jordandobson/wordpress. I roughly tested it in console, but what would be the best way to put code in app?

Comment: Also, to make it clear: this gem does not allow you to "deploy a rails app to wordpress", that is impossible. It allows you to add posts to a wordpress blog using ruby.

Comment: I think you should give more info about your needs. Stackoverflow is not a place where people give you code when you ask. ;)